# Need an explanation of how we search for zeros of a math function using recursive binary search algorithm

Tags: c, function, recursion, math

The following function returns zero in the interval (a,b) of the function: f(x)=5*sin(x)*log(x) with precision eps. 
I don't understand the else part where we have the condition if(f(a)*f(x)<0. 
I do understand that if we have interval (a,b) and f(a)*f(b)<0 it means zero of a math function is in that interval, but I don't understand why using binary search we reduced the right side for that condition.

```
float zero(float a, float b, float eps){

    float x = a + (b-a)/2;

    float val = 5*sin(x)*log(x);
    if(fabs(val) < eps){
        return x;
    }else{

        float left = 5*sin(a)*log(a);
        if(left*val < 0)
            return zero(a, x, eps);
        else
            return zero(x, b, eps);

    }
}
```

for the input: `0.9 2 0.01`
the output: `0.998828`

Comment: Did you mean `zero` and not `zerp`? Also, why are you using `float` and not `double`?

Comment: This code very clearly doesn't compile.  Could you fix the, the formatting of your code and the question please?

Comment: `if (left*val < 0)` is shorthand for “if the function crosses the axis between `a` (with function value `left`) and `x` (with function value `val`)”. The reasoning is that if the function crosses the axis (an odd number of times) between `a` and `x`, then one of `left` and `val` will be positive and one will be negative, so their product will be negative. For this to work, it is a prerequisite that the function have different signs at `a` and `b` so that you know there is at least one crossing between them.

Comment: @Mini Yes. I fixed it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Pls check this image: https://pasteboard.co/Ibe9KdI.png
What about this case?

Comment: @EricPostpischil has already stated that the prerequisite is "that the function have different signs at a and b so that you know there is at least one crossing between them", so the algorithm is not working in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Bisection_method) to find the zeros (also called root). Using this method is like applying binary search again and again until the value is smaller than epsilon. Depending on the sign of the answer, we either continue with the left or right side of the section and refine this process until the value is small enough. [Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/polynomial-functions/zeros-of-polynomials-and-their-graphs/a/positive-and-negative-intervals-of-polynomials) is a detailed example of how this mathematically works.

Comment: But if the graph of a math function were like this one: https://pasteboard.co/Ibe9KdI.png

Comment: That is the catch, it has to be "defined on an interval [a, b] and where f(a) and f(b) have opposite signs"